# Given set of points in 3D, find group of points closest to each other

Tags: geometry, algorithms, 3d

Given a set of any 8 points in 3D space. I want to find a subset of points that are closest to each other.

Application: Assume in a 3D space, I have any 8 colors(represented in RGB). I know how to  calculate the distance between any 2 colors. I want to calculate which points would form the closest cluster.

What we know will work [brute-force]:

- Calculate the distance between all the combinations of colors.
- For each color find which other color is farthest and falls under the Maximum distance and create a subset from those point.
- In each of the set find the set in which the colors form the closest cluster.

Any better algorithm would be helpful.

Links:
[How to calculate the distance between 2 color](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/bugs/fuzz_distance/)

Comment: why reinvent the wheel? see [this](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~matt/courses/cs563/talks/color_quant/CQindex.html) for an overview of color quantization techniques.

Comment: See the paper [Color image quantization by pairwise clustering](http://www.visgraf.impa.br/Projects/quantization/quant.html)  by Velho et al., [pdf](http://www.visgraf.impa.br/Data/RefBib/PS_PDF/color-quant97/main.pdf.gz)

Comment: What do you mean by "max 10% of the point in the center." ? You should take an example.

Comment: Most color quantization algorithms associate each color with a *weight* (often the fraction of image samples (pixels) having that exact color). Many use special colorspaces (other than RGB) that better reflect the human eyes and display devices color sensitivity, so that the Euclidean distance between two colors roughly corresponds to their perceived differences, without too much systematic bias. This way most used colors can be represented exactly, with the rest of the available "palette" providing the other shades (often using dithering, which needs pairs of colors). Perhaps start simpler?

Comment: @JeanMarie I have edited the question to remove the confusion by not complicating it.

Comment: @achillehui Let me check out if quantization solves my problem.

Comment: In all cases, with your $n=8$ points, it is not worth the value to escape from the calculation of the $n(n-1)/2=28$ mutual distances (it is so few computations !) ; once you have them, a natural trend is to sort them and  find a test whether these minimal distances are between the same group of points or not (2 clusters instead of one, etc.) : is it the core of your question ?